# in jade, cannot get include to work when within a script

Tags: node.js, templates, pug

in template, `include` working fine except when in this `script` section:

```
block head2
  title Some Title
  
  script
    function pageInit() {
      include restful.js
      restful.init();
    }
  document.addEventListener('load',pageInit)
```

the `include restful.js` comes through as straight script - jades doe not execute the include.

how do I get `include` dump lines within `pageInit()`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, such action must not be job of templating engine, but assets manager.

Anyway, this feells wrong, but works nevertheless:

```
//- somewhere in head
| <script>
include ../public/javascripts/log.js
| </script>
```